# VBA sees empty cell as not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I want to choose all empty cells in the certain range. However, some empty are not selected. I have checked the format and everything is fine. If I choose these cells and tap on "delete" button, then they are selected.

[image]

```
Sub Name()

Dim ConvRange As Range
Dim ConvCell As Range
   
Set ConvRange = Sheets("Name").Range("E8:H25,K8:N25,Q8:T25,E29:H46,K29:N46,Q29:T46,E50:H67,K50:N67,Q50:T67,E79:H96,K79:N96,Q79:T96,E100:H117,K100:N117,Q100:T117,E121:H138,K121:N138,Q121:T138")
   
For Each ConvCell In ConvRange
    If IsEmpty(ConvCell) = True Then
        ConvCell.Value = "BLANK"
    End If
Next ConvCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably they have an epmty string and therefore are not considered empty. Try `If IsEmpty(ConvCell) = True or ConvCell = vbNullString Then`

Comment: `If Len(CStr(ConvCell.Value)) = 0 Then ConvCell.Value = "BLANK"`.